# What to do with `.git_old`?

Tags: git, github

I maintain a small repo (about 10 files) on one of my Linux boxes. The files are all shell scripts that I use on the box, and edit (***almost*** exclusively) on the box. I also keep it *remotely* on GitHub, and update GitHub when I've made changes.

In October last year, there was a minor disaster: A script (not part of the repo) I had written to automate updates to the repo deleted all of the files in my local copy. I recovered from this, and sidelined my auto-update script until I corrected the issue.

Since then, GitHub has added requirements to use a token, or an SSH key for transactions between the GitHub server, and my local box. I added the SSH key recently, and this seems to be working OK.

I mention all of this history because I've just noticed today that there is an odd hidden file in my local repo: `.git_old`. From the date on the folder, I guess this was created during the restoration of my local repo (a clone of GitHub IIRC).

I have just today made a change to one of the files in the repo, and my (cautious) commit procedure begins as follows:

```
$ git -C ~/MyRepo status --porcelain
 D .DS_Store
?? .git_old/
$ git -C ~/MyRepo add --dry-run --all
remove '.DS_Store'
add '.git_old/COMMIT_EDITMSG'
add '.git_old/FETCH_HEAD'
add '.git_old/HEAD'
add '.git_old/ORIG_HEAD'
...
$

# other commands that will follow to make the commit*ment*: 

$ git -C ~/MyRepo commit -m "$NEWURL"
$ git -C ~/MyRepo push origin master

# at which time my GitHub repo will be in sync with my local repo (?)
```

My proficiency with `git` is quite low, but it seems that the `git add ...` command is telling me that the contents of `.git_old` will be added to the GitHub repo?? - Is that correct?

If it is: I'm not ashamed of my *battle scars*, but I see no purpose in copying them to GitHub either. If `.git_old` serves no future purpose, I'd like to remove it from the repo - and that's the question really - Can `.git_old` be removed without repercussions? Any other insights and advice, esp wrt the final 2 steps in my commit procedure script above are welcome.

Comment: I don't believe Git has any features that would involve touching a `.git_old` directory. I'm going to guess you most likely took a backup of the `.git` folder (which is core to what Git needs to work) and named it `.git_old`. If you don't think you'll need any __local__ branches or stashes that may have been created while you were using the `.git_old` version of history, then I'd say you can remove it without worry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can .git_old be removed without repercussions?

Yes. And add it to your `.gitignore`, as you can see in [this project](https://github.com/trh0/rep4j/blob/64691d7102f93df36beb188a228066228924be74/.gitignore#L7-L11).

Some scripts like [`FriendlyUser/file-track-Dapp/fixgit.sh`](https://github.com/FriendlyUser/file-track-Dapp/blob/595041eca79f5331e3dc9fd1b1c2835d5a5a4319/fixgit.sh) can generate such folder or file:

```sh
# For when you have a corrupted local repo, but a trusted remote.
# This script replaces all your history with that of the remote.
# If there is a `.git`, it is backed up as `.git_old`, 
# removing the last backup.
# This does not affect your working tree.
```